# Electric bike: Do I need display?

Tags: electric-bike

I'm planning to buy an electric bike kit. However, I don't really like adding the display for aesthetic reason. However, the display (either LED or LCD) has function on/off and low/mid/high power on some model and this confuse me.

Can I just have BLDC motor, controller, battery, PAS, and brake sensor and hope it will work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are building your own kit, you can do whatever the heck you want. The reason pre-built ones have them is both safety and convenience -- you want to know when the e-assist is on for safety reasons, what power mode you're in, and how much power you have left so you're not stuck on the road.

Without [blinkenlights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights), it can be hard to diagnose problems, especially on the road. Is your e-assist not working because the battery is low or dead? A bad main power connection? Maybe the brake-cutoff switch is broken, etc. etc.

<sub>If you are aesthetically against the blinkenlights, you can design your own enclosure that is more modest, use dimmer LEDS or tape over them, or relocate them to make them more discrete -- perhaps under the saddle where you can still check them when problems arise.</sub>

Comment: It is handy being able to select max power when you need to climb a steep hill. I would say it's more trouble to get a kit that doesn't contain the display.

Comment: You don't need a display to be able to select power modes (depending on how you build the controller), but I've clarified my answer to accommodate. Thanks Kim!

Comment: Can you tell me more whether it depends on the controller or in general I dont need a display? So for example without a display, how could I turn on the motor

Comment: It entirely depends on the controller and on your own skill in electronics.

Comment: I've been known to tape over excessively bright battery indicator LEDs on bike lights but I wouldn't have thought this was a good solution to aesthetic objections. If I was designing my own system I'd add extra LEDs in fact - to help with some of the reasons you mention (I've had trouble with a broken brake sensor).

Comment: You can also mount the display somewhere other than the handlebars - often they will attach to the seatpost and sometimes to the top or seat tubes. It's still going to be ugly, but it's not as visible.

Answer (score 2):

Well I just use my 48V 1000W electric bike rear wheel 26" without lcd display. No problems. No worries.

On throttle, there is battery power display "full, half and empty".  There is  another signal on battery display as "5 red dots" when press. I can understand how far I can go by first test ride by using these signal.

Throttle can go slow and fast as you want but pedal assist system go full speed.

Comment: Thank you - that's a better answer than your earlier one.   So you're saying that the only information you need is battery status, and everything else is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

It will be very inconvenient without the battery charge indicator. One or another way the battery level should be possible to estimate, and better more precisely than "okay" and "mostly empty".

Other information is useful at times but not vital. But the battery usage may be difficult to estimate and the impact of staying without power in a long trip is major.

Comment: Note that battery indicators can also be on the batteries themselves (Bosch and Shimano do that). Of course with the tendency of integrating the batteries into the frame, they are not visible, but in the case of a conversion, the battery will be visible.

Comment: In my E bike the LED row you talk about is facing down and covered by plastic lid, so not easy to check. But may be possible to do better on custom design.

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant by "integrated design", the row of leds on the Bosch Powertube are for example not visible without removing the batteries, and there are also bikes with plastic covers to hide batteries. But the OP was about a conversion kit, so likely that the battery won't be concealed at all.

Answer (score 1):

The LCD is useful to control the power of the PAS, on traffic you will need to control the power and the PAS works always on full power.